# laravel migration schema builder: deferred constraint checking

Tags: sql, laravel-4, database-migration, schemabinding

i have to insert bulk data into tables and defer foreign key constraint checking until transaction commit.

as in postgresql, `NOT DEFERRABLE` [is the default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) constraint type (mysql innoDB [does not support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) DEFERRABLE constraints at all), how can i change this default within migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You can always run raw MySQL using `DB::raw('...')`. This should do the trick:

```
DB::raw('SET foreign_key_checks = 0;');
```

http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Comment: i'm just doing this, but this(hackish) approach has a big disadvantage:
there is no way to be sure if all constraints is passed after bulk inserting records (by setting foreign_key_checks = 0 at beginning and foreign_key_checks = 1 at the end)